# End tag div seen, but there were open elements

Tags: php, html

This is repeated question but the html code is different here.
I have start `div` tag but even it is saying there is NO start/open elements.

i validated by https://validator.w3.org.

**End tag div seen, but there were open elements.** - `<form action="/ts_s/tss_table_pages.php" method="POST" name="theform">`

**Unclosed element form - last 3rd line**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://localhost/ts_s/images/favicon.ico"/>
<title>TS API</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.stickyheader.js"></script>
<script>
function OpenInNewTab() {
    var win = window.open("choose_affiliate.php", '_blank');
    win.focus();
}
</script>
 <style>
select.custom-dropdown, .tbcolor,.submit_query,.offers_category{
 -webkit-appearance: none;  /*REMOVES DEFAULT CHROME & SAFARI STYLE*/
 -moz-appearance: none;  /*REMOVES DEFAULT FIREFOX STYLE*/
 border: 0 !important;  /*REMOVES BORDER*/

 background-color: #00AEEF;
 color: #fff;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-size: 12px;
 padding: 4px;
 width: 15%;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 100px;
}
div.pagination{
    background-color: #00AEEF;
}
img{
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #888888;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
        <div class="header" style="float:left;">
            <img src="images/logo.jpg" height="80" width="60" alt="Traffc Steer"/>
        </div><!-- header -->
        <h1 class="main_title">Integrated API with Workflow Automation</h1>
        <div class="content">
           <form action="/ts_s/tss_table_pages.php" method="POST" name="theform">
one<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="country[]">
    two<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="country[]">
    three<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="country[]">    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save" onclick="btnClick();"/>

                <div class="label_div" style="float:left;">Type a keyword :</div>
                <div class="input_container" style="float:left;">
                    <input type="text" name="subquery" id="name_id" onkeyup="autocomplet()"/>
                    <ul id="name_list_id"></ul>                    
                </div>

                <div class="lable_div" >
                    <input type="submit" class="submit_query" name="submit_id" value="Submit Query"/>
                    Select Incent Type :<select class="custom-dropdown" name="incent_type" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                        <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: incent_type in <b>C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\ts_s\tss_table_pages.php</b> on line <b>181</b><br />
<option value="none" >All</option><option value="Incent" >Incent</option><option value="Non-Incent" >Non-Incent</option>                    </select>

                    Select Offers Type :<select class="offers_category" name="offers_type" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                        <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: offers_type in <b>C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\ts_s\tss_table_pages.php</b> on line <b>190</b><br />
<option value="none" >All</option><option value="Android" >Android</option><option value="IOS" >IOS</option>                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <input class="submit_query" type="submit" name="update_mail" value="Update Mail"/>
                <input class="submit_query" type="submit" name="new_mail" value="New Mail"/>
                <input class="submit_query" type="submit" name="checkout_mail" value="Checkout Mail" onclick="OpenInNewTab();"/>                
    </div><!-- content -->    
</div><!-- container -->
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Select</th>
<th><a href="tss_table_pages.php?sort=network_id">Network_ID</a></th>
<th><a href="tss_table_pages.php?sort=id">Offer_ID</a></th>
<th><a href="tss_table_pages.php?sort=countries">Countries</a></th>
<th><a href="tss_table_pages.php?sort=name">Name</a></th>
<th><a href="tss_table_pages.php?sort=d_preview_url">Decrypted URL</a></th>
<th><a href="tss_table_pages.php?sort=default_payout">Price</a></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=820' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>820</a></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Voonik_Non Incent - India</td>
                <td>com.voonik.android</td>
                <td>0.4</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=969' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>969</a></td>
                <td>IN</td>
                <td>WeChat - Non incent - CPR - IN</td>
                <td>com.tencent.mm</td>
                <td>0.39</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=526' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>526</a></td>
                <td>EC</td>
                <td>Whatsapp2 - CPA- Claro - Subscription - Non-incent</td>
                <td>http://tss.com</td>
                <td>0.54</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=520' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>520</a></td>
                <td>CO</td>
                <td>Whatsapp CPA (claro) - Subscription - Non-Incent - CO</td>
                <td>http://tss.com</td>
                <td>0.56</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=512' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>512</a></td>
                <td>PA</td>
                <td>Whatsapp Wallpapers CPA (wifi + 3G) - Subscription - Non-Incent - PA</td>
                <td>http://tss.com</td>
                <td>0.36</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=514' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>514</a></td>
                <td>AT</td>
                <td>Whatsapp Wallpapers CPA 3G - Subscription - Non-Incent - AT</td>
                <td>http://tss.com</td>
                <td>11.9</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=616' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>616</a></td>
                <td>IN</td>
                <td>Wooplr - Android - India - Non Incent</td>
                <td>com.app.wooplr</td>
                <td>0.3</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=552' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>552</a></td>
                <td>IN</td>
                <td>Wooplr - Android - Non-Incent - IN</td>
                <td>com.app.wooplr</td>
                <td>0.32</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=71' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>71</a></td>
                <td>UK</td>
                <td>Wowcher - IOS - UK (Incent)</td>
                <td>469033575</td>
                <td>0.9</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=644' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>644</a></td>
                <td>MY</td>
                <td>WuLin - iOS - Non Incent - Malaysia</td>
                <td>961510482</td>
                <td>0.7</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=252' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>252</a></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Wynk - Android - Non-incent - IN</td>
                <td>com.bsbportal.music</td>
                <td>0.43</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=250' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>250</a></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Wynk - Android - Non-incent - IN</td>
                <td>com.bsbportal.music</td>
                <td>0.43</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=254' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>254</a></td>
                <td>IN</td>
                <td>Wynk - Android - Non-incent - IN</td>
                <td>com.bsbportal.music</td>
                <td>0.43</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=168' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>168</a></td>
                <td>IN</td>
                <td>Yatra Android CPI - India</td>
                <td>com.yatra.base</td>
                <td>0.35</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=200' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>200</a></td>
                <td>IN</td>
                <td>Yatra iOS CPI - India</td>
                <td>com.yatra.base</td>
                <td>0.7</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=985' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>985</a></td>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Zalora Fashion Shopping - Non Incent - Android - ID</td>
                <td>com.zalora.android</td>
                <td>0.6</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=228' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>228</a></td>
                <td>AF,AX,AL,DZ,AS,AD,AO,AI,AQ,AG,AR,AW,AP,AU,AT,AZ,BS,BH,BD,BB,BY,BZ,BJ,BM,BT,BO,BQ,BA,BW,BV,BR,IO,BN,BG,BF,BI,KH,CM,CA,CV,KY,CF,TD,CL,CX,CC,CO,KM,CG,CD,CK,CR,CI,CU,CW,CY,DK,DJ,DM,DO,EC,EG,SV,GQ,ER,EE,ET,EU,FK,FO,FJ,FI,FR,GF,PF,TF,GA,GM,DE,GH,GI,GL,GD,GP,GU,GT,GG,GN,GW,GY,HT,HM,VA,HN,HK,IS,ID,INT,IR,IQ,IE,IM,IL,JM,JP,JE,JO,KZ,KE,KI,KP,KR,KW,KG,LA,LB,LS,LR,LY,LI,LT,LU,MO,MG,MW,MY,MV,ML,MT,MH,MQ,MR,MU,YT,MX,FM,MC,MN,ME,MA,MZ,MM,NA,NR,NP,NL,AN,NC,NZ,NI,NE,NG,NU,NF,MP,NO,OM,PK,PW,PS,PA,PG,PY,PE,PH,PN,PL,PT,PR,QA,RE,RU,RW,BL,KN,LC,MF,PM,VC,WS,MS,SM,ST,SA,SN,RS,SC,SL,SG,SB,SO,ZA,GS,ES,LK,SH,SD,SR,SJ,SZ,SE,CH,SY,TW,TJ,TZ,TH,TL,TG,TK,TO,TT,TN,TM,TC,TV,UG,UA,UK,US,UY,UM,UZ,VU,VE,VN,VG,VI,WF,EH,YE,ZM,ZW</td>
                <td>Zero Launcher - Android -  Global</td>
                <td>com.zeroteam.zerolauncher</td>
                <td>0.45</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=230' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>230</a></td>
                <td>TR,IN</td>
                <td>Zero Launcher - Android -  IN & TR</td>
                <td>com.zeroteam.zerolauncher</td>
                <td>0.4</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=232' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>232</a></td>
                <td>US</td>
                <td>Zero Launcher - Android -  US</td>
                <td>com.zeroteam.zerolauncher</td>
                <td>0.9</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=380' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>380</a></td>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Zomato-iOS-incent-ID</td>
                <td>434613896</td>
                <td>0.5</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=382' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>382</a></td>
                <td>PH</td>
                <td>Zomato-iOS-incent-PH</td>
                <td>434613896</td>
                <td>0.5</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=362' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>362</a></td>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Zomato-iOS-Non-incent-ID</td>
                <td>434613896</td>
                <td>0.8</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=364' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>364</a></td>
                <td>PH</td>
                <td>Zomato-iOS-Non-incent-PH</td>
                <td>434613896</td>
                <td>0.8</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=492' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>492</a></td>
                <td>PH</td>
                <td>Zomato Android Non-incent PH</td>
                <td>com.application.zomato</td>
                <td>0.6</td></tr><tr><td style='text-align:center;'>new<input type='checkbox' value='new' name='country[]'/></td>
                <td>tss</td>
                <td><a href='tss_table_pages.php?chkvalue=146' style='color:red' title='Click here to add to mail'>146</a></td>
                <td>IN</td>
                <td>Zopper - Smart Shopping - Android - Incent</td>
                <td>com.zopperapp</td>
                <td>0.2</td></tr></table>

<div style='float:center' class="pagination"><a href="tss_table_pages.php?page=23"> Previous </a><a href="tss_table_pages.php?page=1"> 1 </a><a href="tss_table_pages.php?page=2"> 2 </a>...<a href="tss_table_pages.php?page=16"> 16 </a><a href="tss_table_pages.php?page=17"> 17 </a><a href="tss_table_pages.php?page=18"> 18 </a><a href="tss_table_pages.php?page=19"> 19 </a><a href="tss_table_pages.php?page=20"> 20 </a><a href="tss_table_pages.php?page=21"> 21 </a><a href="tss_table_pages.php?page=22"> 22 </a><a href="tss_table_pages.php?page=23"> 23 </a><span class="current"> 24 </span><span class="disabled"> Next </span></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seen by what? Please add details.

Comment: i got the solution.... my `form` was like starting in `div` tag and it should end in `div` tag only...isn't it? but i end `form` tag at last of documtent.

THANK YOU ALL OF YOU FOR HELPING

Comment: that isn't your only issue, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your closing `</form>` tag is in the wrong place.  It should be right after the last

Comment: the actual code is big. I just put the part where error seen

Comment: Don't expect we solve a HTML formatting problem when you're not showing the full HTML code.

Comment: Ok, now I see the </form> tag, but is obviously in the wrong place. It should be right after the last <input>

Comment: i got the solution.... my form was like starting in div tag and it should end in div tag only...isn't it? but i end form tag at last of documtent.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing `/`'s in some input ends, replace the ones below in yours and it should work

```
one<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="country[]" />
two<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="country[]" />
three<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="country[]" />
```

the whole code blob can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TTuMDvb7NDs41Asq9Qtt?p=preview)

Comment: the actual code is big. I just put the part where error seen.
Now i have updated snippet to the full code.

Comment: i put that code in the html just for testing the checkbox. The above three checkbox are working but checkbox in the table cannot post value. That's why i'm doing validation. Thank you for ur response.